# If $n>1,$ and $I =\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^n}$ then find the value of I.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$
\mbox{If}\quad n > 1\quad \mbox{and}\quad
I \equiv
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{{\rm d}x}{\left(x + \sqrt{\,1 + x^{2}\,}\,\right)^n}
\,,\quad \mbox{then find the value of}\quad I. 
$$
Please suggest how to proceed in such problems I am having no clue about the substitution in this integral.

Thanks..

Comment: Do you know some complex analysis?

Comment: The square root clearly suggests the substitution $x=\tan u$.

Comment: Conjecture: $I_n=\frac{n}{n^2-1}$. I imagine this can be proved by induction, possibly without the need of trigonometric substitutions.

Comment: How about the substitution $x=\cosh t$?

Comment: The sub $x = \sinh t$ works, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\sinh{t}$; then

$$I = \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-n t}  \, \cosh{t} = \frac12 \left (\frac1{n-1}+\frac1{n+1}\right ) = \frac{n}{n^2-1}$$

Note that I made use of the fact that $\sinh{t}+\cosh{t}=e^t$.

Comment: Ninja'ed :). Nice.

Comment: @user111187: o my, I didn't see your comment.  I guess that stuff happens here, especially when a difficult-looking problem has a simple solution.